# How do I start a new game without going bankrupt?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I have completed the game but didn't research large games until year 34. I feel like I've missed out on quite a few aspects of the game, therefore I want to start a new one. Now I know I could just run my company into the ground, but I want my guy to retire rich and happily (yes, I'm one of THOSE people) and it's very time consuming because I have 150 Million. Do you know how to start a new game without just going bankrupt on purpose?

Comment: You can mark the question as answered by clicking on the green mark, it will also reward the one who answered with rep. point.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can simply press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and choose the "New" option:

[image: Screenshot of Menu with "New" option marked]